# what is $\mathcal F, \Omega$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Could anyone write for me what is $\mathcal F, \Omega$ in this situation as the author has not written after he mentioned at the beginning.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks for clearing the notation.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: [Scanned pages aren't allowed on SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is notation for a probability space, i.e.

- $\Omega$ = Simply a set, called "the universum" (intuitively, all possible outcomes of a probability experiment)
- $\mathcal{F}$ = a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, with subsets called "events"
- $\mathbb{P}$ = a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$